# Unable to import python library urllib

Tags: python-2.7, urllib

```
sudo apt-get install python-urllib
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-urllib
```

Why is it coming like this??
Please help out

Answer (score 0):

Consult [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt)

The package either does not exist or is distributed through different software source from the one you are using with `apt-get`